# Constat redirecting to login site

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Let assume that I have `/admin` and `/login` site. User want go to the `/admin` secured site (require login). Spring security ask user about creditials, after login user is redirected to `default-target-url`. Next he try go to the `/admin` and see again login form. What is wrong?

Spring sill require login to the site, I can not go into site.

**Config**

```
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:form-login default-target-url="/succes"/>
        <security:session-management/>
    </security:http>

    <bean id="service" class="com.springapp.mvc.dao.HibernateService"/>

    <bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

    <bean id="saltSource" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
        <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>

 <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="service">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5">
                <security:salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
            </security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want user to login at `/admin` or not?

Comment: @LaurentG I want get to know why after succesfull autorization via form I can not go into the `/admin` site becaues it sill require creditials.

Comment: In that case, please show us your Spring security XML config.

Comment: @LaurentG I did this.

Comment: Sorry I don't see the problem. Maybe `pattern="/admin/**"` (two stars)?

Comment: Could you please share your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Its really interesting and initially I was not able to reproduce as it was working fine for me in normal settings but I was able to reproduce the problem disabling cookies in the browser.

**So the Solution is**

You just need to enable cookies in your browser, as when you login initially it allows you and  passes you to target url (which is not secure in your case) after that when you try to go to `/admin/somepage` it again asks for credentials as session is not tracked.

I hope you know how browser handle cookies and url rewriting for session tracking.

**Note:** This seems just one problem as I am able to reproduce, if this is not your case, you need to share your controllers and steps to reproduce the problem.